# Separatedness of morphisms from separated scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

A scheme $X$ is separated if the canonical morphism $X\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ is separated.  Is it true that if $X$ is separated, then every morphism $X\rightarrow Y$ is separated?

Apologies if this is obviously true or false; being new to schemes I have little intuition how to prove such a thing or how to construct a counterexample.

Comment: See this topic: [https://math.stackexchange.com/...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250947/separated-schemes)